# Show/Hide Select All Tree Checkboxes

Tags: navigation, checkboxes, multi-selection, tree, nodes

We are using a 3-level nav tree (Sport-Country-Competition) with nodes being selected only on the third level.

Upon running usability tests, we identified that the absence of a "select all" option is a pain point for our users. Should the users want to select all the competitions from a Sport-Country, they have to select each node one-by-one, which results in an unnecessary interaction cost.

We are considering replacing the country flag icon with a checkbox, should the user mouse over the country node; this way the user will check the country checkbox for all competitions to be selected.

My questions below:

1. Revealing/Hiding the Select All checkbox will promote recall over recognition; will the impact be considerably bigger from the benefit?
2. Should we expand the country node upon selecting it to show all children being selected instantly?
3. Any other alternatives/suggestions we can think of?

[image: Current State without Select All]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revealing/Hiding the Select All checkbox will not work for tablet/phones as mouseover do not exist. Additionally, the first time user will have a tremendous disadvantage of NOT knowing to look for the SELECT ALL.

Another alternatives/suggestions: add a SELECT ALL as the first choice in each list.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. Forgot to mention that this for Desktop only, therefore, there are no mouse over issues for tablet/mobile. Re your suggestion, do you believe the "Select all" node should be less grayed out so that it's visually less prominent?

Comment: Good observation, @Dimitris. My design proposed a grayed out 'select all' for the sake of faster reading. IMO, users want to scan the list quickly therefore I make 'select all' gray so it does not act as a visual obstacle. But the #1 rule should be: use whatever colors you are currently using elsewhere for 'select all' and do not encourage color-schizophrenia. If you like my answer, how about rewarding me an Answer checkmark?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the mouse over is not good. since we got phone/tabs. Since this is having a very large amount of data we need to group it proper manner.

I'd suggest this.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. The nav tree width is fixed, therefore we won't be able to expand it in order to replicate the solution you suggested.